# Getting key error while iterating through a list recursively and matching value to a dictionary, Python

Tags: python, recursion

My function is failing at the the following input `interpret(["NOT", "true"], {"NOT": "false"})`

Basically the function is about "creating my own" logical value operators and interprets them if the value in the list matches the key in the dictionary. I'm getting `KeyError: "true"` here but I have no idea how to fix it.

Am I doing the recursion wrong or something? It should return "false" as "NOT" is equal to "false" in this case but in other cases it should function as the normal not operator functions if you know what I mean.

The code for my function:

```
def interpret(logicalExpression, interpretation):
    if type(logicalExpression) is str:  #
        if not interpretation:
            return logicalExpression
        return interpretation[logicalExpression]
    elif len(logicalExpression) == 1:
        return interpret(logicalExpression[0], interpretation)
    elif logicalExpression[1] == "OR" and len(logicalExpression) >= 3:
        if interpret(logicalExpression[0], interpretation) == "true" or interpret(logicalExpression[2:], interpretation) == "true":
            return "true"
        else:
            return "false"
    elif logicalExpression[1] == "AND" and len(logicalExpression) >= 3:
        if interpret(logicalExpression[0], interpretation) == "true" and interpret(logicalExpression[2:], interpretation) == "true":
            return "true"
        else:
            return "false"

    if logicalExpression[0] == "NOT" and len(logicalExpression) == 2:
        if interpret(logicalExpression[1:], interpretation) == "false":
            return "true"
        else:
            return "false"
```

Comment: In third level of recursion, *logicalExpression* is *true*, which is not in *interpretation*.

Comment: @pacholik I tried to set it to (logicalExpression[0:], interpretation) but that just threw me recursion errors.

Comment: Yes, naturally.

Comment: What is your *interpretation* dict actually for?

Comment: @pacholik The dictionary containing some variables and said variables either have a key of the value "true" or "false". Like this for example `(["cat_asleep", "OR", ["NOT", "cat_gone"]],
               {"door_open" : "false", "cat_gone" : "true", "cat_asleep" : "true"})`.      It gets if "cat_asleep" is "true" or "false" form the dictionary and so on, the output for this one would be "true"

Answer (score 0):

#### The error is in your input.

You pass `"true"` in *logicalExpression*, but you don't pass `"true"` in *interpretation*. *KeyError* is correct behavior.

I think you want to pass *interpretation* like `{"true": "true", "false": "false"}`

```
>>> interpret(["NOT", "true"], {"true": "true", "false": "false"})
'false'
```